# Actuate 7 - Resize frame depending on the containing objects

Tags: report

I don't know if this is the place to ask this question, but if it is:

Is it possible to dynamically resize a frame depending on the objects it
contains. Objects inside also resize dynamically according to multiline text
size.

Thank you,
Radu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default frames will automatically resize larger to fit their contents (under the dynamic size and position section - canincreaseheight). Make all your contents as small as the minimum they would be and then the frame as small as those contents. If any of the fields wrap and expand the frame will resize accordingly.

Comment: I think the problem is the field isn't resizing. The value for the canincreaseheight property is set to true to both the frame and the field inside the frame.

Comment: The field will have to be a dynamic text control (not label or regular text control). Also make sure the Multiline (under text placement) is set to true - although I belive that is the default.